# Can I apply a class to a table row containing a link, rather than to the link itself?

Tags: jquery

The following code adds a class to a link and removes another class from the same link:

```
 $('a[href$="' + myStr + '"]').removeClass('yes').addClass('no');
```

The link appears in a table. How would I apply this change in class to the ROW that the link appears within in the table, rather than to the link itself? I've been playing around with the 'parent' command however either that isn't it or I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: parent() returns the immediate parent of each element in the selection. parents() returns all of the ancestor elements of each element in the selection. closest(selector) returns the single closest ancestor element (including the current element) for each element in the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a[href$="' + myStr + '"]').closest('tr').removeClass('yes').addClass('no');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$('tr:has(a[href$="' + myStr + '"])').removeClass('yes').addClass('no');
```

Comment: `closest` is better because it works with nested rows (it will return the closest one, while `:has` while return both)